# Editing css in individual tumblr posts

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am by no means a coder but I know I need to fix an image source bug in my individual tumblr post CSS. I must have a shoddily coded theme that makes me have to manually put in the image source code for each photo in photo sets. But when I click on the HTML on an image post, I can't actually edit the CSS but just the html. Can you even do that?

Comment: Can you send a link to one of these posts? Tumblr usually defaults to adding photosets inside an iframe. I would recommend writing some common lines of css into the template to target that type of post as presumably this issue could arise again, and you don't want to have to write inline css every time you post surely?

Comment: http://cafedumonstre.tumblr.com/post/97938149911/my-favorite-art-from-the-de-young-museum-today

Comment: @lharby see the code I posted in the comment in the answer below. I don't know how to properly post code on this site yet!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

**Before:**

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{‌​PhotoURL-500}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

**After:**

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{‌​PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear why you can't edit your css. But if that's the case you can try styling your images by using [style](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) within your < img > tag.

```
<img src="your-img-path" style="height:100px; width:100px;" />
```

Comment: Like I don't know if your familiar with tumblr but if you are doing an image post, and then click on the 'html' option, you can only edit the html of the writing and not of the images themselves. Maybe this is an issue with tumblr's interface but i've been googling and I can't figure it out at all.

Comment: I just read that within an individuals tumblr theme there is css for each 'type' of post: text, photo/photosets, quote, audio, etc. So the problem must be there.